# Heavy computational function without blocking ui

Tags: react-native

I am new to React Native. I have a function that is doing some heavy computation which takes arround 30 seconds to finish when called. This would be a horrible expirience if the user has to wait for this to finish. What would be the best practice for this?

Answer (score 2):

if you can run it on native you can create a bridge method and run it on a background thread that resolves a promise with a result. maybe an easier option is to use [react-native-background-task](https://github.com/jamesisaac/react-native-background-task)